# Interbench Benchmark Code

Tags: c, linux, windows, benchmarking

I want to ask anyone of you here is familiar with this function as below in the Interbench. I want to port this to windows platform but keep failing. I can only get microsecond accuracy by using timeval instead of timespec. And in the end , there will be error : divide by zero and access violation exceptions

```
unsigned long get_usecs(struct timeval *myts)
{
    if (clock_gettime(myts))
        terminal_error("clock_gettime");

    return (myts->tv_sec * 1000000 + myts->tv_usec);
}

void burn_loops(unsigned long loops)
{
    unsigned long i;

    /*
    * We need some magic here to prevent the compiler from optimising
    * this loop away. Otherwise trying to emulate a fixed cpu load
    * with this loop will not work.
    */

    for (i = 0; i < loops; i++)
        _ReadWriteBarrier();
}
void calibrate_loop()
{
    unsigned long long start_time, loops_per_msec, run_time = 0;
    unsigned long loops;
    struct timeval myts;

    loops_per_msec = 100000;

redo:
    /* Calibrate to within 1% accuracy */
    while (run_time > 1010000 || run_time < 990000) {
        loops = loops_per_msec;
        start_time = get_usecs(&myts);
        burn_loops(loops);
        run_time = get_usecs(&myts) - start_time;
        loops_per_msec = (1000000 * loops_per_msec / run_time ? run_time : loops_per_msec );
    }

    /* Rechecking after a pause increases reproducibility */
    Sleep(1 * 1000);
    loops = loops_per_msec;
    start_time = get_usecs(&myts);
    burn_loops(loops);
    run_time = get_usecs(&myts) - start_time;

    /* Tolerate 5% difference on checking */
    if (run_time > 1050000 || run_time < 950000)
        goto redo;

    loops_per_ms = loops_per_msec;
}
```

Comment: The function you provided depends heavily on function `get_usecs()` for computing timing, and it also relies on functions `burn_loops()` and `Sleep()` for some of its behavior.  *None* of these is a standard C or even POSIX function, so you haven't given us enough information to inform an appropriate answer.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I have added in the needed functions.

Answer (score 0):

The only `clock_gettime()` function I know is the one specified by POSIX, and that function has a different signature than the one you are using.  It does provide nanosecond resolution (though it is unlikely to provide single-nanosecond precision).  To the best of my knowledge, however, it is not available on Windows.  Microsoft's answer to obtaining nanosecond-scale time differences is to use its proprietary ["Query Performance Counter" (QPC) API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Do put that aside for the moment, however, because I suspect clock resolution isn't your real problem.

Supposing that your `get_usecs()` function successfully retrieves a clock time with microsecond resolution and at least at least (about) millisecond precision, as seems to be the expectation, your code looks a bit peculiar.  In particular, this assignment ...

```
loops_per_msec = (1000000 * loops_per_msec / run_time
        ? run_time
        : loops_per_msec );
```

... looks quite wrong, as is more apparent when the formatting emphasizes operator precedence, as above (`*` and `/` have higher precedence than `?:`).  It will give you your divide-by-zero if you don't get a measurable positive run time, or otherwise it will always give you either the same `loops_per_msec` value you started with or else `run_time`, the latter of which doesn't even have the right units.

I suspect the intent was something more like this ...

```
loops_per_msec = ((1000000 * loops_per_msec)
        / (run_time ? run_time : loops_per_msec));
```

..., but that still has a problem: if 1000000 loops is not sufficient to consume at least one microsecond (as measured) then you will fall into an infinite loop, with `loops_per_msec` repeatedly set to 1000000.

This would be less susceptible to that particular problem ...

```
loops_per_msec = ((1000000 * loops_per_msec) / (run_time ? run_time : 1));
```

... and it makes more sense to me, too, because if the measured run time is 0 microseconds, then 1 microsecond is a better non-zero approximation to that than any other possible value.  Do note that this will scale up your `loops_per_msec` quite rapidly (one million-fold) when the measured run time is zero microseconds.  You can't do that many times without overflowing, even if `unsigned long long` turns out to have 128 bits, and if you get an overflow then you will go into an infinite loop.  On the other hand, if that overflow happens then it indicates an absurdly large correct value for the `loops_per_msec` you are trying to estimate.

And that leads me to my conclusion: I suspect your real problem is that your timing calculations are wrong or invalid, either because `get_usecs()` isn't working correctly or because the body of `burn_loops()` is being optimized away (despite your effort to avoid that).  You don't need sub-microsecond precision for your time measurements.  In fact, you don't even really need better than millisecond precision, as long as your `burn_loop()` actually does work proportional to the value of its argument.